# Why use assembly for mod operation instead of %?

Tags: solidity, assembly, modulo

I'm trying to understand why assembly for this sum is required?
Why not use `+` and `%` ?

```
    _structHash = keccak256(
        abi.encode(
            _blockhash,
            totalAddresses,
            gasLeft,
            _externalRandomNumber
        )
    );
    _randomNumber  = uint256(_structHash);
    assembly {_randomNumber := add(mod(_randomNumber, _maxNumber),1)} // why?
    winningNumbers[0]=uint8(_randomNumber);
```

Comment: Which contract is that from? If they have a Github, please try asking there. And if you get an answer, please post back here :)

Comment: This comes from pancake swap lottery.

Comment: OK. Usually it is better to include that information in the question. If they have a Github, that would be another place to try asking.

Comment: @eth, please see my answer!

Comment: @MilaA I did not run your code but like the approach you've taken. There might be other stuff at https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues?q=mod  I've upvoted and it's nice redigaffi has accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First of all, I'd like to explain what they *[the PancakeSwap team]* intend to accomplish with these lines...*

---

> **MOD:** This opcode calculates the remainder of the second-to-top element
> on the stack divided by the top element and pushes the result onto the
> stack. It is used for performing modulo operations.

So `MOD` is basically an equivalent of `%`.

The reason `PancakeSwap Lottery` contract utilizes the `modulo` function for the pseudo number generation is *that the algorithm it uses is a slightly tailored **mixed congruential pseudo-number generation method**.*

And if you want the generated number to remain within specific integer constraints (e.g., `< 1,000`), you need to use the `modulo` function to trim the number without clearing its **"randomness"**.

`add(mod(_randomNumber, _maxNumber),1)` <-- `add(..., 1)` is used here to handle the cases when the `remainder = 0`, apparently because they want the random number to always remain `> 0`.

<s>*Although adding `1` **IN *EVERY* CASE** feels unnatural to me, because when the `remainder` is `> 0`, why would I want to add `1` to it? That feels unfair to the winner who is the `remainder` (when `remainder` is `> 0`)...*</s>

---

I wrote a small test to check whether there were any practical constraints that made the developers use assembly instead of high-level syntax:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract Test {
    uint8 _maxNumber;
    uint256 _pseudoRandomNumber = 2345100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;

    constructor() public {
        _maxNumber = uint8(1000);
    }

    function modulo() external view returns (uint256 result) {
        return (_pseudoRandomNumber % _maxNumber) + 1;
    }
}
```

... it compiles well and returns `33`.

**WHICH IS *NOT* WHAT WE WOULD EXPECT IT TO RETURN, RIGHT?**

[image: result_modulo_33]

---

But comparing that result (`33`) with the result of the assembly operations surprised me even more...

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract Test {

    function modulo() external view returns (uint256 result) {
        uint8 _maxNumber = uint8(1000);
        uint256 _pseudoRandomNumber = 2345100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
        assembly {
            result := add(mod(_pseudoRandomNumber, _maxNumber), 1)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: assembly-mod-result-is-quite-unexpected-actually]

The result is `1`. That is **correct**!

---

And here is a unified test, *for clarity*:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract Test {
    function moduloPlain() external view returns (uint256 result) {
        uint8 _maxNumber = uint8(1000);
        uint256 _pseudoRandomNumber = 2345200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003;
        result = (_pseudoRandomNumber % _maxNumber) + 1;
    }

    function moduloAssembly() external view returns (uint256 result) {
        uint8 _maxNumber = uint8(1000);
        uint256 _pseudoRandomNumber = 2345200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003;
        assembly {
            result := add(mod(_pseudoRandomNumber, _maxNumber), 1)
        }
    }
}
```

**That results in:**

[image: result-3]

---

As we can tell from these tests, the lower-level assembly `mod` and `add` functions give more accurate and precision-friendly results than the higher-level `%` and `+` operators do for when the input integers are of different bit sizes.

---

And, while I cannot answer the question why is there a **HUGE**
difference between the high-level and low-level interpreted snippet results, that is the **REASON** why t*he PancakeSwap team* used the **assembly** for these math operations for their `Lottery` contract.

***Though one curious thing I noticed is the following...***

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract Test {
    function moduloPlain() external view returns (uint256 result) {
        result = (2345200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003 % 1000) + 1;
    }

    function moduloAssembly() external view returns (uint256 result) {
        uint8 _maxNumber = uint8(1000);
        uint256 _pseudoRandomNumber = 2345200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003;
        assembly {
            result := add(mod(_pseudoRandomNumber, _maxNumber), 1)
        }
    }
}
```

... Gives an **absolutely** correct, and — what's more important — *an expected*, result:

[image: curious-result-number-4]

---

To conclude, it looks like the culprit is something in how higher-level Solidity treats integers of different bit sizes when calculating the **modulo** function.